# Nesting While Loops (C#)

Tags: c#, debugging, while-loop, visual-studio-2015, nested

Good Evening Coders-
  For my assignment in my software development class I have to nest while loops.  For the outer loop I have to count down from 5 to 1 and the inner loop I have to count from 0 to 10 in increments of 2.  My problem is that I see no errors for one and two, I had class tonight and the instructor went over the program and the code is identical.  The outer loop's output is correct, but the inner loop's output seems to start at 4, when it should start at 0, skipping over 2.  The inner loop also counts up to 12 when the code clearly states up to 10. I have tried to declare the "i" variable to 0 with the same outcome.  That is why I am thinking it is a bug. I am fairly new to coding so I am not familiar with using the bug tools.  Your input is greatly appreciated! :)

```
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int k = 5; //assigned variable for 1st loop  
        int i; //assigned variable for 2nd loop

       while (k > 0) //run first loop as long as "k" is greater than 0
        {
            i = 0;//set i variable to 0 
            while (i <= 10)//run second loop as long as "i" is greater than or equal to 10
                           //second loop runs until first loop is over
            {  
                i += 2;//count "i" varible in increments of 2
                Console.WriteLine("k= {0} i= {1} ", k, i);//print index value for both variables

            }
                k--;//subtract "k" variable by increment of 1

        }

    }
}
```

}

Below is the expected output (notepad) and the output I received (VB).

[image: Expected Output]

[image: Output of Code Given Above]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inner loop, you are incrementing i before the writeline, so it will never print 0 (it immediately starts at 2 for each inner loop).  Reverse those lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("k= {0} i= {1} ", k, i);    
i += 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version:

```
k = 5
while k > 0
    i = 0
    while i <= 10
        puts "k = #{k}: i = #{i}"
        i += 2
    end
    k -= 1
end
```